# Extract raster pixel values along a polyline in PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgis, raster, polyline

I have a PostGIS database with a table containing rasters, and I want to extract the values of the pixels along a polyline (an arbitrary number of coordinate points) at a specific time. So the objective is:

1. Select the relevant tile(s) given a polyline and timestamp
2. Return the values of all pixels that are crossed by the polyline

So each output row would contain a coordinate pair and the corresponding pixel value.

From what I have googled so far I understand that I either

1. convert the line to a raster and then do an intersection, or
2. convert the raster to a vector thing and then do an intersection

However, I am unable to apply the few examples I have found to my case. Can someone give a hint?

The raster table is called `air_temperature` and the relevant columns are `rast` and `timestamp`. I have learned that I can provide a proper geometry as, for example, `"st_transform(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTILINESTRING ((7.294832 52.697831, 7.294074 52.698534))'), 4326), 3857)"`.

I think I can select the relevant tiles and timestamps by including a where caluse as follows:

`where st_intersects(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTILINESTRING ((7.294832 52.697831, 7.294074 52.698534))'), 4326), 3857), rast) and timestamp='2017-01-01 01:00:00'`

But how does the `select` part look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you should [upload your rasters](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Loading_Rasters) into database and than [employ](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html) `st_value()` to extract pixel bands. That would be faster than converting raster into geometry and further processing it, but the drawback is that you, most probably, will be able to analyze line vertices only (not each and every point).

Comment: The rasters already are in a database, so I don't really understand what you mean. Also I'm already using queries to extract single points using <code>st_value</code> and some other functions.

Comment: Can you, please, edit your question to give me some clue of what exactly you're trying to achieve (what is output data format / table columns that suit your purpose)?

Comment: Since your polyline is constructed from point samples, I would still recommend to stick to those points only as polyline vertices and get pixel bands values in those particular points. Otherwise, you're going to need to rasterize your polyline (because vectorizing rasters would take ages) with `st_asraster()`, intersect the route-raster with background-raster with `st_intersection()` and then extract band values of resulting raster which is still going to be real slooooow.

Comment: That sounds plausible. I'll try to construct something along those lines (haha) and then use the st_value() functionality I already have. Thanks for looking into this!